# ElasticSearch Inner Hits on has_parent nested Inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I've searched for this and haven't found anything that says whether this is or is not supported.  According to Elastic [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits):

> "Inner hits can be used by defining an inner_hits definition on a
>   nested, has_child or has_parent query and filter. "

I want to use inner_hits on a has_parent, nested object.  I've tried it as illustrated in the example below.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Example Scenario (I've simplified the data and properties for the purpose of this post)

> We store task title & description translations as a nested object in
>   the parent task. Each nested title has an iso code and a translated
>   title & description.  We distribute child tasks to, in some cases,
>   thousands of users so it didn't make sense replicating the
>   title/description into each child object.

**Parent Task Example**

```
{
  "_id": "parenttask_177448",
  "startDate": "2020-05-01T00:00:00",
  "endDate": "2020-05-05T00:00:00",
  "type": "task",
  "taskjoin" : "parenttask",
  "priorityId": 1,
  "translations": [
    {
      "title": "This is a test task",
      "description": "test",
      "localeIsoCode": [
        "en-US"
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "tester",
      "title": "Ceci est une tâche de test",
      "localeIsoCode": [
        "fr-FR"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Children Task(s) Example**

```
{
    "_id": "childtask_12345",
    "taskSubType": "distributed",
    "subtasks": [],
    "startDate": "2020-03-19T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2020-03-19T00:00:00",
    "taskJoinField": {
      "name": "childtask",
      "parent": "parenttask_177448"
    },
    "assignedUserId": 12345,
    "assignedUserName": "Bob Jones"
}
```

Relevant part of the query I'm running that brings back no inner hits results

```
{
  "has_parent": {
    "ignore_unmapped": true,
    "parent_type": "parenttask",
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "ignore_unmapped": true,
        "inner_hits": {
          "name": "innerhits_task",
          "_source": {
            "includes": [
              "title"
            ]
          }
        },
        "path": "translations",
        "query": {
          "term": {
            "translations.localeIsoCode.keyword": {
              "value": "fr-FR"
            }
          }
        },
        "boost": 1.1,
        "_name": "nested_isocode"
      }
    },
    "score": true,
    "boost": 1.1,
    "_name": "parent_isocode"
  }
}
```

**Relevant Mapping**

```
{
  "thinktime_dev_7003_tasks": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "assignedUserId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "assignedUserName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "taskJoinField": {
          "type": "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals": true,
          "relations": {
            "parenttask": "childtask"
          }
        },
        "localeIsoCode": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "locationId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "translations": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "description": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "image": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "isPrimary": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "localeIsoCode": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              },
              "url": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting results back from the child tasks but no inner hits matches.  If I move the inner hits to the has_parent, I get all the translations back.

My question is whether doing a parent nested inner hits is possible in Elastic?  I'm surprised I didn't find anyone else trying to do this or examples on the Internet.  This seems like a pretty common use case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of your mapping?

Comment: I added the mapping to my original post above.  I fixed one typo in the name of the TaskJoinField.